# How to stop the flat file disassembler debatching

Tags: biztalk, flat-file

I have a flat file input that looks like this:

```
D1~0000002~917~NEGS515968~NEFS1606091~09062016~Some Random Company ~33330~
D2~0000003~NEFS1606091~1~~~0~0~NEGS~AC40010~54110~C90~0000~00~0000~33330~EXEMPT~0~~~~~~~~~~~
D1~0000004~2112~NEGS518497~NEFS1606091~09062016~Another random company~6890~
D2~0000005~NEFS1606091~1~~~0~0~NEGS~AC40010~54110~C90~0000~00~0000~6890~EXEMPT~0~~~~~~~~~~~
```

There are two record types, denoted by the 1st column - either a "D1" or "D2".

I've used the wizard to define the following flat file schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Random.Unit4.Supplier.Schemas.Suppliers.NegsFF" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Random.Unit4.Supplier.Schemas.Suppliers.NegsFF" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="complexity" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="NegsFF" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="NegsFF">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="postfix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="DataRecType1">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo tag_name="D1" structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="~" child_order="prefix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="SequenceNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="OracleSupplierNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="AlternateSiteName" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="InvoiceNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="4" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="InvoiceDate" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="5" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="InvoiceHeaderDesc" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="6" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="AmountGrossInvoice" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="7" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="8" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="DataRecType2">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo tag_name="D2" structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="~" child_order="prefix" sequence_number="2" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="SequenceNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="InvoiceNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="InvoiceLineNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="4" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank2" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="5" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="QuantityInvoiced" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="6" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="UnitPrice" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="7" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="InvoiceLineDesc" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="8" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="CostCentre" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="9" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Subjective" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="10" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Objective" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="11" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="ProjectGroup" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="12" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Balancing" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="13" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank3" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="14" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="AmountGrossLine" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="15" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="VatCode" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="16" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank4" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="17" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank5" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="18" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank6" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="19" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank7" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="20" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank8" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="21" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank9" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="22" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank10" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="23" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank11" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="24" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank12" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="25" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank13" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="26" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank14" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="27" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank15" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="28" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Now, if I right-click the flat file schema from within VS and select validate instance, the XML that is created contains only one record - even though the input flat file contains multiple D1 and D2 records. If I build and deploy into BizTalk, when I push the message through a receive location then the file is debatched and I get two XML output files.

I had thought that by setting the "DataType1" and "DataType2" record element's "Max Occurs" property to "unbounded" this would prevent debatching. Can anyone see where I went wrong please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you have defined the repeat (maxoccurs) on the DataRecType1 & DataRecType2 and as part of a **Sequence**, which means it expects 1 to many of DataRecType1 and then 1 to many of DataRecType2.

e.g.

```
D1~0000002~917~NEGS515968~NEFS1606091~09062016~Some Random Company ~33330~
D1~0000004~2112~NEGS518497~NEFS1606091~09062016~Another random company~6890~
D2~0000003~NEFS1606091~1~~~0~0~NEGS~AC40010~54110~C90~0000~00~0000~33330~EXEMPT~0~~~~~~~~~~~
D2~0000005~NEFS1606091~1~~~0~0~NEGS~AC40010~54110~C90~0000~00~0000~6890~EXEMPT~0~~~~~~~~~~~
```

You either need to have a **repeating record** that encompasses both DataRecType1 & DataRecType2 or to have a **repeating choice** node that expect either DataRecType1 or DataRecType2.

You do this by changing NegsFF to have a **Group Max Occurs** set to **unbounded** and setting the **Group Order Type** to **Sequence** or **Choice** as appropriate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Random.Unit4.Supplier.Schemas.Suppliers.NegsFF" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Random.Unit4.Supplier.Schemas.Suppliers.NegsFF" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="complexity" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="NegsFF" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="NegsFF">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="postfix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <b:groupInfo sequence_number="0" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="DataRecType1">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo tag_name="D1" structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="~" child_order="prefix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="SequenceNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="OracleSupplierNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="AlternateSiteName" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="InvoiceNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="4" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="InvoiceDate" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="5" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="InvoiceHeaderDesc" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="6" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="AmountGrossInvoice" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="7" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="8" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="DataRecType2">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo tag_name="D2" structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="~" child_order="prefix" sequence_number="2" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="SequenceNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="InvoiceNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="InvoiceLineNumber" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="4" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank2" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="5" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="QuantityInvoiced" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="6" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="UnitPrice" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="7" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="InvoiceLineDesc" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="8" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="CostCentre" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="9" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Subjective" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="10" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Objective" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="11" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="ProjectGroup" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="12" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Balancing" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="13" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank3" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="14" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="AmountGrossLine" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="15" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="VatCode" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="16" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank4" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="17" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank5" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="18" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank6" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="19" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank7" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="20" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank8" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="21" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank9" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="22" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank10" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="23" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank11" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="24" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank12" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="25" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank13" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="26" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank14" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="27" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Blank15" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo sequence_number="28" justification="left" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```